# Require ffi-napi on browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, dll, ffi, quasar-framework

I am trying to create a local browser-based application.
I need to have access to some dlls so I used a module called `ffi-napi`:

Example (what I need to use is not specifically the `libm` module, just simplifying the example):

```
    var ffi = require('ffi-napi')

    var libm = ffi.Library('libm', {
      'ceil': ['double', ['double']]
    })
    libm.ceil(1.5)
```

This works fine when on I am running on Electron. But when I compile it for use with the browser, I am getting this error message (which is being thrown by `Webpack`/`node-gyp-build`:

```
Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: require is not defined"
```

I understand that `require` is not native on the browser mode, but the framework I am using, I believe, already has `browserify` integrated (I am using `Quasar framework`).  I think so because the other local modules I can use `require()` on the browser just fine.

Is there any way I can use `ffi-napi` on the browser?

Help!